# Newman : Fill Heap Memory Error. On long run

Tags: postman, newman

I have a problem with overfilling Heap memory, using long newman runs.
I run collection using the below command line :

`newman run C:\temp\004_L10_Orchestrator_L10_UAT_V4.0.postman_collection.json -g C:\temp\Euro_globals.json -e C:\temp\UAT-L10-WagerOperations.postman_environment.json --folder “5104 - Tzoker (Channel 2)” -k -n 200`

after 100 iteration we take the below error :

```
<— Last few GCs —>

[10028:000001BE90168DD0] 355619 ms: Scavenge 2042.2 (2049.5) -> 2041.1 (2049.5) MB, 4.4 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.234, current mu = 0.129) allocation failure
[10028:000001BE90168DD0] 355636 ms: Scavenge 2042.7 (2049.7) -> 2041.9 (2050.7) MB, 5.8 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.234, current mu = 0.129) allocation failure
[10028:000001BE90168DD0] 355660 ms: Scavenge 2044.7 (2052.0) -> 2043.9 (2056.1) MB, 5.7 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.234, current mu = 0.129) allocation failure

<— JS stacktrace —>

==== JS stack trace =========================================

0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF788EA154D]
1: StubFrame [pc: 00007FF788F11F49]
Security context: 0x00d1dc3c0921
2: baseClone [0000008D72BE2A39] [C:\Users\Agent\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:1] [bytecode=000001855E0FE891 offset=0](this=0x0098e94c2531 ,0x011436a82d41 <String[#7]: integer>,5,0x0110437ab189 <JSFunction (sfi = 00000150CA97CAB1)>,0x011436a83259 <String[#4]…

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200122.122008.10028.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
1: 00007FF788290BEF napi_wrap+126287
2: 00007FF78822DF26 public: bool __cdecl v8::base::CPU::has_sse(void)const __ptr64+34950
3: 00007FF78822EBF6 public: bool __cdecl v8::base::CPU::has_sse(void)const __ptr64+38230
4: 00007FF788A57FEE private: void __cdecl v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached(void) __ptr64+9
```

i have increased the memoery availble for the Heap memory but the effect was that from 100 we pass to 150 iteration .